# I am facing the issue with installation of the package

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-10, github-packages, laravel-package

I have forked a Laravel drag and drop menu builder package from github pacakge name is **efectn/laravel-menu-builder** and I have changed the name of the package in the composer.json file with my name.  Because the package https://github.com/efectn/laravel-menu-builder was not working on the Laravel 10 it was working on laravel 9  and after changing the name of the package in my github repo the package is not installing.

Like when I run the command **composer require rah1595/laravel-drag-menu**  in my cmd to install this package in my laravel project I am getting an error

```
In PackageDiscoveryTrait.php line 368:

  Could not find a matching version of package rah1595/laravel-drag-menu. Check the package spelling, your version co
  nstraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (dev).
```

And when I am trying to install the package through the command **c****omposer require rah1595/laravel-drag-menu:dev-master** I am getting an error

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires rah1595/laravel-drag-menu, it could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

This is my composer Code

```
{
    "name": "rah1595/laravel-drag-menu",
    "description": "Wordpress like drag & drop menu builder for Laravel",
    "keywords": ["Laravel", "Menu", "Wordpress", "Builder", "Drag and Drop"],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Rah",
            "email": "rah38951@gmail.com",
            "role": "Maintainer"
        },
        {
            "name": "Muhammed Efe Çetin",
            "email": "efectn@protonmail.com",
            "homepage": "https://6tel.net",
            "role": "Maintainer"
        },
        {
            "name": "Rendy Harimayco",
            "email": "rendyharimayco@gmail.com",
            "role": "Original Developer"
        },
        {
            "name": "Cristian Garcia",
            "email": "informacion@cristiangarcia.co",
            "role": "Original Developer"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "illuminate/support": "^5.5|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0|^9.0|^10.0",
        "vendor/package": "1.1.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Efectn\\Menu\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Efectn\\Menu\\MenuServiceProvider"
            ],
            "aliases": {
                "Efectn": "Efectn\\Menu\\Facades\\Menu"
            }
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/rah1595/laravel-drag-menu"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

And this is my github package so that you can check it

**rah1595/laravel-drag-menu**

As I am trying to install the laravel package which I have forked from github the package name is  **efectn/laravel-menu-builder**  but I am unable to do as I have already explained above

I want to install it normally like other laravel package we install from the github

Comment: composer installs packages (when using the package name) from https://packagist.org/ and not directly from github so you either need to publish your fork there or [add a private repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs)

Comment: The reason `composer require rah1595/laravel-drag-menu:dev-master` failed is because your repository url is wrong, the url must be able to clone your package from git. Modify the url of composer.json to **https://github.com/rah1595/laravel-drag-menu.git** should be able to install.

Comment: Now I have achieved the installation in the Laravel 9 now I want is that this should get installed in the Laravel 10 but I am unable to achieve this as I am getting the error can you please help me that how can I achieve this I have tried may thing but nothing is working so please help me to update this in Laravel 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close. The problem is that composer doesn't know where to look for to install your package. It searched in packagist by default, but couldn't find the package. You could follow the comments and publish it in packagist, but there's a much simpler way.

To make it a lot simpler, you can give instructions to composer to look in a specific github repo to download this package instead of from packagist. This is possible by adding the `repositories` key in the `composer.json` of the **project you are running composer require in** and specifying it to look in your github repo. Here's [a link to the documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs).

So you can add the following to the `composer.json` of your project ( again, just reminding, this needs to be added to your project, not to the package )

```json
{
    "name": "my/project",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/rah1595/laravel-drag-menu"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1"
    },
    // Skipping rest
}
```

After adding this, `composer require rah1595/laravel-drag-menu` should work if everything is done correctly

Comment: And this is not working in the Laravel 10 so please also help me that what changes I should do so it work with Laravel 10

Comment: You can get the package on the GitHub for source code when I am trying to install in the Laravel 10 I am getting the error

In PackageDiscoveryTrait.php line 331:

  Could not find a version of package rah1595/laravel-drag-menu matching your minimum-stability (stable). Require it
  with an explicit version constraint allowing its desired stability.